# How can I read CtClass from .class file?

Tags: java, javassist

I've got `.class` file. I want to open it by `javassist`, add class annotation and save. How can I get `CtClass` instance from `.class` file?

ps. I don't know its dependencies / package / name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the `CtClass` from a class file you can use the method [`ClassPool.makeClass`](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/ClassPool.html#makeClass%28java.io.InputStream%29). This method takes as an argument an input stream from which it reads the class file.

```
import javassist.ClassPool;
import javassist.CtClass;

ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
CtClass ctClass = pool.makeClass(new FileInputStream("pathTo\Test.class"));
System.out.println(ctClass);
```