# Replace string in pre-existing jar file

Tags: java, jar

I'm looking for a way to replace `%%__USER__%%` string in a pre-existing .jar file and then let the user to download it. I don't have any code to share as this is only theoretical, and I have no clue where to start from.

I'm not aware of any way this could be achieved, possibly through bytecode? Any help would be appreciated.

More information:
Files are already compiled and stored on web server. They are uploaded by community members, and the `%%__USER__%%` code would be used to track license analytics. Would need to change this code to downloading user's code every time file is downloaded.

Comment: with what would you like to replace it? wouldn't it make more sense, to use environment variables

Comment: Are you saying that your webapp has a file (a jar file to be specific) that a user can download, the jar file has some kind of text file in it (e.g. a property file), and you want to live modify the embedded text file to insert the users name, as the file is downloaded by the user? I.e. the jar file downloaded by the user has been "branded" with the users name?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, basically that.

Comment: @Lino it's for a "licensing" system, of course it will be possible to abuse / bypass it, but currently it's what I need.

On download the string should be replaced with user's name (a string as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JAR file is basically just a ZIP file. To live update a file in the JAR file, as it is being downloaded by a user, you can use [`ZipInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) and [`ZipOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html).

Example:

```java
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"foo.jar\"");
try (
    ZipInputStream in = new ZipInputStream(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("template.jar"));
    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
) {
    for (ZipEntry zipEntry; (zipEntry = in.getNextEntry()) != null; ) {
        out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(zipEntry.getName()));
        if (zipEntry.getName().equals("special.txt")) {
            copySpecial(in, out);
        } else {
            copyStream(in, out); // doesn't close streams
        }
    }
}
```

```java
static void copySpecial(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out)));
    for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
        line = line.replace("%%__USER__%%", "John Doe");
        writer.println(line);
    }
    writer.flush();
    // Don't close reader/writer
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but it is not entirely clear what `copyStream(in, out)` does

Comment: @Lino I thought the name would be enough to show that it copies all bytes from `in` to `out`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (assuming you want / need to change that String inside an existing class):

- extract jar
- read and modify the class file with javassist, or maybe ByteBuddy? I haven't done this, but this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066810/how-can-i-read-ctclass-from-class-file) seems to imply that it is possible.
- zip / jar again (if it was signed you might have to resign)